# Mismatch between previous and updated bundle versions

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, nsbundle

Each time I attempt to publish an update to an app I receive this automated email response moments later:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "App Name". 
>   Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Version Mismatch - Neither CFBundleVersion ['9.1'] nor CFBundleShortVersionString ['9.1'] in the Info.plist match the version of the app set in iTunes Connect ['2.41'].

I understand why the message is being generated but I would like to resolve the issue without having to compromise the version # by making it higher than it actually is.

---

*Being the first app I had ever developed, I was pretty clueless when it came time to publish the app and in frustration of the process I mistakenly defined the version number to some extreme value because I was, at the time, getting stuck with another error that was preventing me from completely the process .. the other error which I've since forgotten exactly, was related to the version number being incorrect.  So I finally thru my hands in the air, set the version number to 8 and was able to complete the process.*

Since then, I'm still pretty clueless but I've learned a thing or two, and the current version of the app is 2.41.  When I prepare an update on iTunes Connect I set the version to 2.41.  But if I define 2.41 in CFBundleVersion or CFBundleShortVersionString, Xcode outright refuses to upload the binary and demands a version greater than the previous version which has now surmounted to 9.1.

Obviously, any users of the app would be quite confused if the version jumped from 2.41 to 9.1 overnight.

Answer (score 0):

It was you who defined the new version as 2.41 in iTunes connect. Any new version should be higher than the last one. So the straightforward solution is removing the 2.41 version from iTunes Connect and add a new 9.1 version. Then iTunes Connect and your binary will be in accordance and you will be able to upload the new version.